# Where is the R executable that comes with Jupyter on OS X?

Tags: r, jupyter

I see that I have an R kernel installed (R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)) but I don't know where to find it on the disk. Any pointer?

Comment: Are you referring to IRkernel? In that case `.libPaths()`

Comment: does `R.home()` from R notebook not pointing you to right path?

Comment: Nice. R.home("bin") works.